# How to prevent Angular/Webpack leaving references to dev directories on production code

Tags: angular, webpack, web-deployment

Angular/Webpack is leaving "comments" on production (dist folder) code referencing development directories which include my username.

Example:

- main.js:

> module.exports = **webpack_require**(/*!
> C:\Users\cristian.abelleira\myproject\src\main.ts */"./src/main.ts");

How can I prevent this behaviour?

**Note:** I used "ng build" command to generate /dist folder

**angular.js**: https://gist.github.com/CrAbelleira/11c2eb2d25ade5a7ac7bf34d0b8e7952

Comment: Build it on another machine, maybe in a docker container?

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu Is that the only way to achieve it? This references are visible 
through the browser's console. Even if I use another machine I would have references to "C:\Whatever"..

Comment: I don't seem to be getting the same behavior as you. My production build does not include that string. Which version of Angular do you use?

Comment: How does your `angular.json` look like? The build artifacts should be minified, which includes removal of comments.

Comment: Are the comments removed when you run `ng build --configuration production`?

Comment: @CristianAbelleira If your version of angular is below 12 then you need to use `ng build --prod` command to build project. `--prod` is important.

Comment: @JSONDerulo nope, they still there.

Comment: Please add your `angular.json` to the question. With a new project generated by `ng new` this doesn't happen. Looks like misconfiguration.

Comment: @JSONDerulo angular.js added

Comment: @CristianAbelleira What version of angular are you using? Try once deleting `node_module` folder, and reinstall again using `npm i` in commad line of project. Then see what happens.

Comment: @GRD Angular CLI: 13.0.1 Node: 12.20.0  Package Manager: npm 6.14.8 OS: win32 x64

Comment: I found the problem. It was a missconfiguration so "--configuration production" wasn't being executed properly. Sorry for the mistake and thank you everyone.

Comment: @CristianAbelleira Can you please explain bit more about what issue you have at your side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It was a misconfiguration that was preventing the command "***ng build --configuration production***" to be executed with the "***--configuration production***" flag properly.

After compiling with this flag, the references dissapeared.

Comment: Upvoted your answer. Glad that you find out the solution.